# Дождаться завершения jquery-анимации

Tags: javascript, jquery, анимация

Есть jquery-плагин. Его метод `destroy` должен удалить элемент из dom'а.

Но есть вероятность, что перед вызовом `destroy` при помощи jquery-анимации анимируется скрытие этого элемента. Как дождаться завершения анимации, если она действительно есть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

добавить удаление в очередь анимации, если очереди нет элемент удалится сразу если есть то в конце очереди

```
div.queue(function(next) {
 div.remove();
 next();
})
```

кликните по элементу пока он движется или в конце анимации

```js
  $(function() {
    var div = $("div")
    div.click(function() {
      var animate = div.queue("fx").length
      div.text(animate ? "animate" : "destroy");

      div.queue(function(next) {
        div.css({
          color: "red"
        }).text("destroy");
        //div.remove();
        next();
      })

    }).animate({
      "margin-left": 200
    }, 5000)
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="border: 1px dashed Gray; padding: 5px; width: 100px;height: 100px;"></div>
```

Comment: Пропустил аргумент `next`